# Is HMAC padding the same as bcrypt?

Tags: hmac, padding

I have been watching Christof Paar on his [YouTube lectures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaH8UG2yMg4) also I used bcrypt to store two passwords with salts and I find that I have a few questions.

I am interested in what bcrypt does to the start of the final hash.

```
$2a$10$
```

I have two thoughts on this:

1. I know that Christof is speaking about HMACS in the lecture above not bcrypt, but the start of the final hash does seem alot like what he describes as 'padding', **is it the same?**.
2. The first part (`$2a`) is saying that there are two vars; a salt and a message, **but I am not sure what the `a` is for here?** The second part is the iterations or something to do with the salt length I think as there is no space between the salt and the message.

Comment: Welcome to Crypto.SE! Please don’t get me wrong… but you’ve put so much non-relevant information into your question, that I am not sure if everyone will grasp what you’re actually asking. Maybe you could [edit your question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/17795/edit) and focus a bit more on the core of the question itself, instead of the chit-chat? I’m pretty sure that doing so will increase your chances of receiving usable answers – instead of the down-votes and close-votes your question is currently attracting.

Comment: Looks much better now. (Btw.: thanks for not feeling stepped on your toes.)

Comment: I find it a good judge of character when one offers advice rather than shooting down - it gives the offending party chance to 're-target'.

Answer (score 2):

This is not padding, nor is it related to the concept.

The output from the bcrypt library you're using is in a format inspired by Linux [`crypt(3)` format](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/crypt.3.html#NOTES). Dollar signs are field separators. `2a` is the algorithm identifier. The full list is:

```
ID  | Method
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
1   | MD5
2a  | Blowfish (not in mainline glibc; added in some
    | Linux distributions)
5   | SHA-256 (since glibc 2.7)
6   | SHA-512 (since glibc 2.7)
```

The second field, `10`, is the strength factor; I believe this corresponds to $2^{10}$ iterations of the algorithm. The salt and hash are stored concatenated with one-another — they are both fixed widths (128 bits for the salt, 184 bits for the hash), so it is easy to extract them.

Comment: so this password protection method is unsafe?